# How is variable implemented internally in Swift?

Tags: swift

In C, a pointer variable is essentially an unsigned int that holds the memory address that contains the value that it points to.  How does variable in Swift work?

Comment: Related http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl7.html

Comment: you should have read the documentation about _Swift_, before you asked such a question: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ClassesAndStructures.html that explains it really well, which object and how will be passing to a method.

Comment: Thanks holex.  I have removed that part of the question addressed in the doc.